# How to Handle Pandas Operation Creating -Inf Values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have a long table of daily return data for stocks, and I am trying to calculate their % returns by this,

```
data['return'] = data['avg'].pct_change()/100
data.dropna(inplace=True)
```

And the values I get are normal.

However, trying to do any other operations on the data now gives me an `NaN`, which confused me since the original data was well-behaved and I made sure to drop any new `NaN`'s. Turns out the `pct_change()/100` operation creates a `-Inf` at one point, which is just infuriating.

Since I am assuming the `-Inf` gets created bec. a certain neg. % change was too low, how do I get around pandas operations in general making the same mistake?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: *"Since I am assuming the -Inf gets created bec. a certain neg. % change was too low..."*  You'll get `inf` or `-inf` if one of the values in the series is 0.  Check your input for zeros.

Comment: By the way, it looks like "pct_change()" isn't an accurate name for this operation.  It doesn't actually compute a *percent*.  It is the fractional or relative change.   The value computed by `pct_change()` for the change from `a` to `b` is `(b - a)/a`.  So you probably shouldn't divide by 100.